Pressing Ctrl+( with highlighted text converts them into some markup code and won't undo
I am new to Mathematica, and I am using Mathematica v12.3. I am writing some math notes which include text and some equations. I know that in a text cell I can press CTRL+( and start typing some equations and they would appear in mathematical notation. But sometimes if an equation is highlighted and I accidentally press CTRL+(, the equation is converted to some kind of markup code. For example x^2+9-50 would become \!( *SuperscriptBox[(x), (2)] + 9 - 50)
The strange thing is that most of the time this action cannot be undone with CTRL+Z, and the undo is greyed out in the Edit tab. I have to close the file and reopen it to get it to the state it was last saved.

I want to know what is this markup code, and how I can undo this action, and why it does what it does, why only on highlighted text?

Its not an answer, but undo is also bugged in v14. Commenting out via keyboard shortczt and undoing doesnt undo the comment, and in the worst case deleted part of the code without reversibility.

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! If you want to know more about the syntax you are seeing, I suggest reading String Representation of Boxes. I have also edited your question and included a screen record of the behaviour you are observing. I hope this is what you meant.

The thing you described happens often. It is a feature, rather than a bug. To transform the formula back do the following: 1) select the transformed expression  2) go to Menu/Evaluation/Evaluate in Place. Done. However, if the formula is short I often retype it. Have fun!

@AlexeiBoulbitch The Evaluate in Place works only with some equations, not every. also it does not convert them back into what they were before, for example it converts into x^2 instead of original $x^2$ - but the main issue is that why this can not be undo. and what is the purpose of this function.

@Asim Please see the answer.

@AlexeiBoulbitch
Try writing $
\sin ^2(\theta )+\cos ^2(\theta )
$
in a text cell and highlight this equation then press CTRL+( two time, now you can undo the action but you will get ^ instead of proper superscript notation,  you will never get the same notation again, How do I get it back to the original math notation it was before doing CTRL+C two times.. that is my question.

@Asim 1) In my version Mma 14.1 it works perfectly. No problem. 2) If instead of sin^2(θ)+cos^2(θ) you would write according to Mma syntax, namely, Sin[\[Theta]]^2+Cos[\[Theta]]^2 then you will be able to wrap it by TraditionalForm like this: TraditionalForm[Sin[\[Theta]]^2+Cos[\[Theta]]^2] and then select and Evaluate in Place. It is the regular way to do such things. 3) I do not know for sure, why Undo does not work. However I guess that it is since when your expression transformed it changed the artificial Traditional Form to the natural Input Form. The latter is more stable.

Please see the result of the application of the Evaluate in Place to the in-line math cell

If in some cases it does not work wrap the math expression by the TraditionalForm like the following:
TraditionalForm[x^2]

and apply the Evaluate in Place afterwards.
Concerning your main issue, I do not know.
Have fun!

this does not help, Yes evaluate in place works with normal short equations but not a complex one.it is not about wrapping the text in TraditionalForm, its about why if accidentally highlighter text get a CTRL+( command can not be undone in usual way. I have tried many different ways to reverse it but every time i do something it make worst and that also can not undo. I just can't understand the purpose of this behavior.
